# Magento2 : Product Import not working properly

Tags: magento-2.1.7, importexport

I have imported two product into magento2 via CSV. After import it said `"imported successfully"`, two products created but no product name, price, images etc updated with product. 
Even earlier import was working properly.

I didn't figure out what causing this issue.

Please suggest?

Comment: Can you please maybe upload the used .csv?

Comment: yes we should use filename.csv only. have you selected "update (or) Replace"?

Comment: did you check the exception logs ?

Comment: How can I upload .csv file in the post?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa, there is no exception log created.

Comment: Does it give a success message or an error message?

Comment: It is returning success message, Even I used same format which was working earlier.

Answer (score 0):

@vinaya kindly check default csv format , then try to import file. 
I am sure some columns name might have been mistakenly changes , hence you might be now seeing blank field. let me know your feedback.